# What is the magic to Windows impersonation with LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

From my reading on user impersonation on Windows, one should properly use the LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS logon type for impersonating a user to a database. Using Matt Johnson's nice impersonation wrapper (originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/115690) and then polished up [here](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation)), I tried to test this out--here is my entire program except for constants defining my particular DOMAIN, USER, PWD, and CONN_STRING.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SimpleImpersonation;

namespace ImpersonationDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static SqlConnection _connection;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Impersonation.LogonUser(
                    DOMAIN, USER, PWD, LogonType.NewCredentials))
            {
                GetOpenConnection();
                CheckDbCredentials();
                CloseConnection();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CheckDbCredentials()
        {
            using (
                var command = new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT nt_user_name, SUSER_SNAME() "
                    +"FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID",
                    _connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
                            reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private static void GetOpenConnection()
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection(CONN_STRING);
            _connection.Open();
        }

        private static void CloseConnection()
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**But that does not work.** The output reports **me** (my underlying logged in user) from both `nt_user_name` and `SUSER_NAME()`. (And SQL Profiler reports exactly the same thing; the query in code is simply a convenient way to see what SQL Profiler tells me.)

If I change from `LogonType.NewCredentials` to `LogonType.Interactive` (these enums have the values you would expect, as defined on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LogonUser)), then it does work--the above code reports the correct DOMAIN and USER impersonation. But this also means the current session is being impersonated which I do not want--I only want the DB connection to be impersonated.

I thought I found one glitch in the above--Johnson's Impersonation wrapper hard-codes the logon provider as `LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT`, when the [LogonUser API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) clearly states that the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` logon type is supported only by the `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50` logon provider. So I grabbed the source and added a parameter to allow specifying the requisite logon provider... but that made no difference.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Taking a step backwards from the issue: If you're going to logon at your DB server instance using Integrated Security, you shouldn't have to rely on impersonation at all; in that case, **1.** using a SQL Server login would be the easier option. If you're using Integrated Security, **2.** simply allow the target users to login (but restrict their rights on the server & database as much as possible); or (even better:) **3.** only let a service access the database, and have your application access only the service, which performs its own authentication & authorization.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, @stakx; however, in this instance I do not have the flexibility to make those architectural changes. And besides, I may not ever be able to get a sound night's sleep again until I find out why the above fails :-) !

Comment: What happens if you use C to get a LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS token and then launch a separate process with the token to do the SQL work on your behalf?  (The new process could be in C#.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, I am ashamed to say, was right in front of me all along. The LogonUser API states:

> This logon type allows the caller to clone its current token and specify new credentials **for outbound connections**. The new logon session **has the same local identifier** but uses different credentials for other network connections. *[emphasis mine]*

But my database is on the same machine as my running program so by definition it will not show the new credentials! I am confident the impersonation will work correctly with `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` once I move my database to a different box. *Sigh.*